# parse JSON from a jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json

I can successfully get back what looks like a JSON object, but I get a non-whitespace error when I parse it and when I don't parse it, I can't access the elements. Basically, I just want to access each element in teh JSON and display it. Here's the code: (below the code is my returned JSON (or what appears to be JSON)

```
$('#cardText').change(function(){
            if($('#cardText').val().trim().length == 9)
                {
                    $.ajax({

                        url: 'components/Person.cfc',

                        //GET method is used
                        type: "POST",

                        //pass the data        
                        data: {
                            method: "getGroup",
                            uid: $('#cardText').val(),
                            },

                        success: function(response) {

                            //obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response); -- I get a non-whitespace error if I do this
                            var Col1 = response.COLUMNS[0]; -- this gives me response.Columns is undefined

                            $('#form_result').html(response);

                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                alert('Time out error.');
                            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                            } else {
                                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                }); 
            }
        });
```

returned data:

```
{
    "COLUMNS": ["PLAN", "NAME", "ID", "ISSUE", "TYPE", "LASTUSED", "BALANCE"],
    "DATA": [["DINING STAFF CAFE 1919 ", "YOUNG, MARIA ", 8.03976343E8, "2001-04-02", 2.0, "2012-01-27", 1]]
}​
```

from notepad (limited the data)
{"COLUMNS":["PLAN","NAME"],"DATA":[["DINING STAFF CAFE 1919 ","YOUNG, MARIA "]]}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a funky character after the last curly brace.  Try pasting your JSON into Notepadd++.

Comment: Here's a limited amount of values, but I still get the non-white error if I try and parse it. This is without any parse, calling response to the div directly.

{"COLUMNS":["PLAN","NAME"],"DATA":[["DINING STAFF CAFE 1919 ","YOUNG, MARIA "]]}

Answer (score 0):

There is a zero-width unicode character U+200b in the sample returned data you have pasted, between the closing `}` and the newline.  This prevented firefox from accepting the snippet.  How did it get there?